# Tensorflow: train a neural network using all training data

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

This may be a basic question, but I'm new to neural networks (and machine learning, in general).

I'm up to reading the last excerpt of TensorFlow code at http://www.brightideasinanalytics.com/rnn-pretrained-word-vectors/. I can see that word IDs are looked up and that the word embedding for the correct word (in a training instance) is looked up.

But the call to sess.run() only deals with one training instance.

What steps do I need to be thinking about so that I modify this sort of code to be like the code at https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/eager, which loops through the entire training data set?

(That second tutorial doesn't use word embeddings - it's doing Iris classification - and its use of grad and loss functions seems rather different to the optimiser used for the RNN.)

Comment: Did you note the `while`-loop beginning in line 138 and calling `sess.run` in line 160 where in each step a different piece of training data is fed?

Comment: @spettekaka Yes, and thanks for replying. And now I notice that offset is increased at the end of the loop.

Comment: So does this already answer your question or do you have further problems understanding the code?

Comment: @spettekaka This answers my question. Thanks.